# Javascript: convert number of days to years, months and days

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have days, months and years. I'm doing calculations between them. That means I have to divide 2 years 3 months and 10 days by 1/4. Now i have following code:

```
const getCurrentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
const timeEnd = moment(moment(DefEndDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
const diff = timeEnd.diff(getCurrentDate);
const diffDuration = moment.duration(diff);
const diffCount = moment.duration(diff).asDays();
console.log(diffCount);
console.log("Years:", diffDuration.years());
console.log("Month:", diffDuration.months());
console.log("Days:", diffDuration.days());

const diffCount = moment.duration(diff).asDays(); //Get it as days
const [unserve, setUnserve] = useState(''); //set value to variable
    const res = unserve.split('/'); //split 1/4 to 1.4
    const x = parseFloat(res[0] + "." + res[1]); //convert it to float
    var quotient = Math.floor(diffCount/x); //calculate
    console.log(quotient);
    //returned 832 / 1.4 = 594 days
```

Now I need to return the output number (days) to the year, month and day. I can't do that. How do I convert? And another question is, can this way be the optimal solution?

Comment: Try [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format)

Comment: @GennadyDogaev thanks, but i need do it without additional libs.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What are your inputs and desired output?

Comment: @OktamYaqubov well, you already using momentjs...

Comment: `2 years 3 months` --- which year and which months?  Number of days in year or month is not constant

Comment: A month can be 28, 29, 30, or 31 days. A year can be 365 or 366. So how are you going to handle that? What result do you want for December 30, 2018 to March 1 2019, and what result do you want for December 30, 2019 to March 1, 2020?

Comment: `timeEnd.diff(getCurrentDate)` throws an error because strings don't have a *diff* method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't decide whether what you really want to do is divide a date range in to a fixed number of periods with equal days, or to start with a date, add a period in years, months and days to get an end date, then divide that into equal periods.

The following assumes the latter.

> I have to divide 2 years 3 months and 10 days by 1/4

The number of days covered by that period varies depending the dates it is to and from, so you have to start with the start and end dates of the range.

In your code:

```
const getCurrentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Sets *getCurrentDate* to a string like 2020-02-11.

```
const timeEnd = moment(moment(DefEndDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

Creates a moment object from the string value of *getCurrentDate* and sets *timeEnd* to another string.

```
const diff = timeEnd.diff(getCurrentDate);
```

This attempts to call the *diff* method of *timeEnd*, which is a string. Strings don't have a *diff* method so the expression returns undefined, attempting to call it throws an error something like `TypeError: '2020-02-11'.diff is not a function`.

The rest of your code seems to be based on a algorithm

If you have a predetermined period in years, months days, etc. you can start with a start date, add the period, then get the number of days difference. Divide that difference by the number of periods you want, then add that sequentially to get the various end dates.

The following example uses moment.js since that's what you appear to be using, however a version without a library is about the same difficulty. It returns an array of dates, starting with the start date so there is one more date than periods.

```js
function getDates(
  start = new Date(),
  years = 0,
  months = 0,
  days = 0,
  parts = 1) {
  
  // Get start and end as moment objects
  let m = moment(start).startOf('day');
  let end = moment(m);
  end.add({years:years, months:months, days:days});
  
  // Get days difference and number of days to add for each period
  let daysDiff = end.diff(m, 'days');
  let f = daysDiff / parts;  
  let dayArray = [m.format('YYYY-MM-DD')];
  let i = 0;

  while ((f * ++i) <= daysDiff) {
    let d = moment(m).add(f * i, 'days')
    dayArray.push(d.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  }
  
  return dayArray;      
}

// Get dates for 4 even periods over 2 years, 3 months and
// 10 days from today
console.log(getDates(new Date(), 2, 3, 10, 4));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

As the sub–period length is nearly always not an even number of days (in the above case it's about 207.5), I've allowed formatting to effectively truncate the decimal part of a day. You might want to use some other rounding algorithm that more evenly distributes the remainder.

If, on the other hand, you have start and end dates and want an equal number of periods, the following is much simpler (and doesn't use a library):

```js
// Helpers - use UTC do avoid DST issues
function toUTCDate(s) {
  let b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], --b[1], b[2]));
}

function formatUTC(date) {
  return date.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
}

/* @param {string} start - date string in format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
** @param {string} end   - date string in format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
** @param (numbe} n - number of required periods
** @returns {Array} array of date strings in format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
*/
function periods(start, end, n) {
  let s = toUTCDate(start);
  let e = toUTCDate(end);
  let diff = e - s;
  let f = diff / n;
  let result = [formatUTC(s)];

  // Allow for rounding of decimal f in comparison
  while (e - s > n) {
    s.setTime(s.getTime() + f);
    result.push(formatUTC(s))
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(periods('2020-02-09','2022-05-19', 4));
```

The two methods produce slightly different results, you'll need to work out if that matters or not.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I used such code to convert from seconds to hours, minutes and seconds:

```
var hours = Math.floor(sec / 3600);
var minutes = Math.floor((sec - hours * 3600) / 60);
var seconds = Math.round(sec - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60);
```

Math with days, months and years should be somewhat similar but my rusty brain doesn't want to think about it

**UPD**

This function seems to do what you need

```
const daysFmt = days => {
  const years = Math.floor(days / 365);
  const months = Math.floor((days - years * 365) / 30);
  const d = Math.round(days - years * 365 - months * 30);

  let res = [];
  if (years > 0) {
    res.push(years + ' y');
  }
  if (months > 0) {
    res.push(months + ' m');
  }
  if (d > 0) {
    res.push(d + ' d');
  }

  return res.join(', ');
}
```

But this solution has one nuance: it assumes that month = 30 days. You might want to add `if` statement to return '1 m' if input is `31` or just return number of days if it is less than 32. Test results:

```
daysFmt(31);
"1 m, 1 d"
daysFmt(180);
"6 m"
daysFmt(185);
"6 m, 5 d"
daysFmt(356);
"11 m, 26 d"
daysFmt(365);
"1 y"
daysFmt(420);
"1 y, 1 m, 25 d"
daysFmt(3650);
"10 y"
daysFmt(3685);
"10 y, 1 m, 5 d"
```